Issue with Running OpenCV Live View Window on Raspberry Pi via Remote-SSH in VS Code
I have a Windows 10 Development PC (WinPC) connected directly to a Raspberry Pi 4 B (RPi) via Ethernet LAN. The WinPC has Internet access through a WLAN USB adapter, while the RPi does not. A Logitech camera is connected to the RPi.
HW-Setup:

Using Visual Studio Code, I can successfully SSH into the RPi and run simple Python scripts, like a "Hello World" program.
However, I encounter an issue when running a Python script (cameraTest.py) that uses the cv2 package to open a live view from the camera. The script is as follows:
import cv2
    
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cv2.namedWindow("test")

while True:

    ret, frame = cam.read()

    cv2.imshow("test", frame)

    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    
    if k%256 == 27:

        print("Escape hit, closing...")

        break
  
cam.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Behavior:
When I run the script on the RPi remotely via MobaXterm from my WinPC, the camera live view window opens without any issues.

When I try to run the same script using Visual Studio Code via Remote-SSH, the live view window does not open, and I receive the following error message:
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/master/Desktop/ObjectDetection/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.



Question:
What could be causing this issue when using Visual Studio Code's Remote-SSH feature, and how can I resolve it to successfully display the camera live view?

Edit (it works now in Visual Studio Code!):

run MobaXterm and SSH (with X11-Forwording enabled) to RPi
run comment export DISPLAY=:10
then run python cameraTest.py


